# Java: removing a specified number of elements from a queue

Tags: java, queue

I have to write a program that creates a queue of Strings. It asks the user to input a number n for which he will have to enter n number of names in the queue. Then until the queue is empty, the program

1. displays the name on top of the queue
2. asks the user a number of names to  be deleted.
3. deletes the number of names specified
4. display the name(s) deleted

The program should use only the add(), remove(), isEmpty() and element() methods.
Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
package lesson1;
import java.util.*;


public class MyClass1{

public static void main(String[] args) {

Queue <String> strings= new LinkedList<String>();


Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter the number of names, n.");
int n= input.nextInt();

System.out.println("Please enter " +n+ " names");

for(int i=0;i<n; i++){

    strings.add(input.next());

}

System.out.println("\nDisplaying the names:\n");
for(String object: strings){

    System.out.println(object);
}

      while(!strings.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("The name in front of the queue is: " + strings.element());


        System.out.println("Please enter the number of names to be deleted:");
        int del= input.nextInt();

        for(int i=0; i<del; i++){

        System.out.println("Name removed:"+strings.remove(i));

       }
      }

  }

}
```

The problem is that it is printing *false* for the names being deleted because remove() is a boolean method. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is this a homework questions?

Comment: remove returns the removed element. It doesn't return a boolean.

Comment: @Eran It is returning _false_ for the Name removed:

Comment: @Eran You are right.. I actually should not have used `System.out.println("Name removed:"+strings.remove(i)); but `System.out.println("Name removed:"+strings.remove());` , that is without the _i_ ..Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `poll` and `remove` returns the deleted object but poll does not throw exceptions if that the problem, no one of them return boolean.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < del; i++) {
    System.out.println("Name removed:" + strings.poll());
}
```

Comment: `remove(index)` can't return `false` it has to have return [Object value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove(int)).

Comment: @Diksha Can you please attach your input and the output ?

Comment: @AmgadMHM You are right that both `poll` and `remove` returns the deleted object.. I actually should not have used System.out.println("Name removed:"+strings.remove(i)); but System.out.println("Name removed:"+strings.remove());` , that is without the i .. Thanks a lot!